# Specific Rails routes password protected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I want a password <strike>site wide</strike> just like Rack's Basic AUTH

**/config.ru**

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
end

run Rails.application
```

But **I don't want it to block paths** `/API` and `/mailgun/incoming_email` with password access.  Can I accomplish this in Rack?  Or should I implement a scope within the routes.rb that almost all resources are behind a Rack (enter once) password?

For the record I am using Devise within the site... that's separate.  I need a sitewide password before it.

### [Revised Question]

#### Specific Routes

I would like to password protect only the root path `/` and `/visitors` with the Rack like password.  I've seen something used in a Rails routes.rb file before with a **lambda** condition requiring the password.  I'm not having luck finding that information at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My website already redirects unauthenticated Devise users to `/users/sign_in`.  So I only needed to password protect `/`, `/users/sign_in`, and `/users/sign_up`.  This is how I did it.

**config.ru**

```
class RootSiteAuth < Rack::Auth::Basic
  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if ['/', '/users/sign_in', '/users/sign_up'].include? request.path
      super
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end

use RootSiteAuth, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
end

run Rails.application
```

And it works.  Every controller that has `before_filter :authenticate_user!` redirects to the Rack password page.  After authentication we're good to go.  Anything without the filter permits outside access as planned.  ^_^

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfectly for Jekyll-Rack apps as well. I just implemented this exact code block, swapping out `run Rails.application` with `run Rack::Jekyll.new`.

Comment: Since it is been 6 years, Is this still the best way to do it or can this be done in another better way? (the code still works in Rails 4 btw)